# How can a heap be used to optimizie Prim's minimum spanning tree algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree

I have to solve a question that is something like this:
I am given a number N which represents the number of points I have. Each point has two coordinates: **X and Y.**

I can find the distance between two points with the following formula:
**abs(x2-x1)+abs(y2-y1)**,
(x1,y1) being the coordinates of the first point, (x2,y2) the coordinates of the second point and `abs()` being the absolute value.

I have to find the minimum spanning tree, meaning I must have all my points connected with the sum of the edges being minimal. *Prim's algorithm is good, but it is too slow*. I read that I can make it faster using a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) but I didn't find any article that explains how to do that.

Can anyone explain me how Prim's algorithm works with a heap(some sample code would be good but not neccesarily), please?

Comment: @kiss-o-matic Really?

Comment: Are there edges between all pairs of points? If it is the case, a heap is useless.

Comment: Yes there are. Why is a heap useless then?

Comment: @ArifOzturk Because the time complexity is O(E lg V). If E is O(V^2), then that's O(V^2 lg V), which is worse than the adjacency matrix's O(V^2).

Comment: If you actually want this to be fast, you should run Prim on the L1 Delaunay triangulation.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I read a little bit about Delaunay triangulation but I can't understand how that can help me in this question.

Comment: I think it reduces the number of edges to a reasonable amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to solve this problem efficiently(in `O(n log n)` time), but it is not that easy. Just using the Prim's algorithm with a heap does not help(it actually makes it even slower), because its time complexity is `O(E log V)`, which is `O(n^2 * log n)` in this case.

However, you can use the Delaunay triangulation to reduce the number of edges in the graph. The Delaunay triangulation graph is planar, so it has linear number of edges. That's why running the Prim's algorithm with a heap on it gives `O(n log n)` time complexity(there are `O(n)` edges and `n` vertices).  You can read more about it here(covering this algorithm in details and proving its correctness would make my answer way too long): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_minimum_spanning_tree. Note that even though the article is about the Euclidian mst, the approach for your case is essentially the same(it is possible to build the Delaunay triangulation for manhattan distance efficiently, too).

A description of the Prim's algorithm with a heap itself is already present in two other answers to your question.

Answer (score 0):

From the Wikipedia article on [Prim's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm#Time_complexity):

> [S]toring vertices instead of edges can improve it still further. The heap should order the vertices by the smallest edge-weight that connects them to any vertex in the partially constructed minimum spanning tree (MST) (or infinity if no such edge exists). Every time a vertex *v* is chosen and added to the MST, a decrease-key operation is performed on all vertices *w* outside the partial MST such that v is connected to w, setting the key to the minimum of its previous value and the edge cost of *(v,w)*.

Answer (score 0):

While it was pointed out that Prim's with a heap is O(E log V), which is O(n^2 log n) in the worst case, I can provide what makes the heap faster in cases other than that worst case, since that has still not been answered.

What makes Prim's so costly at O(V^2) is the necessary updating each iteration in the algorithm. In general, Prim's works by keeping a table of your vertices with the lowest length to other vertices and picking the cheapest vertex to add to your growing tree until all are added. Every time you add a vertex, you must then go back to your table and update any vertices that can now be accessed with less weight. You then must walk back all the way through your table to decide which vertex is cheapest to add. This setup - having to pick the next vertex (O(V)) V times - gives the O(V^2).

The heap is able to help this running time is all cases besides the worst case because it fixes this bottleneck. By working with a minimum heap, you can access the minimum weight in consideration in O(1). Additionally, it costs O(log V) to fix a heap after adding a number to it to maintain its properties, which is done E times for O(E log V) to maintain the heap for Prim's. This becomes the new bottleneck, which is what gives rise to the final running time of O(E log V).

So, depending on how much you know about your data, Prim's with a heap can certainly be more efficient than without!